# webkit-filter on Edge different than Chrome

Tags: css, webkit

When applied on Chrome, the following rule applies to all elements of the body not having the -webkit-filter.

```
body {
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%) !important;
}
```

But on Edge, this seems to have no effect. Is there a workaround on Edge ?

Answer (score 0):

Your rules should look like this:

```css
body {
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%) !important;
    filter: invert(100%) !important;
}
```